# writing/reading binary file in Nim

Tags: io, binaryfiles, nim-lang

What's the best way to write and read a binary files in Nim? I want to write alternating floats and ints to a binary file and then be able to read the file. To write this binary file in Python I would do something like

```py
import struct

# list of alternating floats and ints
arr = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]

# here 'f' is for float and 'i' is for int    
binStruct = struct.Struct( 'fi' * (len(arr)/2) ) 
# put it into string format
packed = binStruct.pack(*tuple(arr))

# open file for writing in binary mode
with open('/path/to/my/file', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(packed)
```

To read I would do something like

```py
arr = []
with open('/path/to/my/file', 'rb') as fh:
    data = fh.read()
    for i in range(0, len(data), 8):
        tup = binStruct.unpack('fi', data[i: i + 8])
        arr.append(tup)
```

In this example, after reading the file, arr would be

```
[(0.5, 1), (1.5, 2), (2.5, 3)]
```

Looking for similar functionality in Nim.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you should find everything you need in the [streams](http://nim-lang.org/docs/streams.html) module. Here is a small example:

```nim
import streams

type
  Alternating = seq[(float, int)]

proc store(fn: string, data: Alternating) =
  var s = newFileStream(fn, fmWrite)
  s.write(data.len)
  for x in data:
    s.write(x[0])
    s.write(x[1])
  s.close()

proc load(fn: string): Alternating =
  var s = newFileStream(fn, fmRead)
  let size = s.readInt64() # actually, let's not use it to demonstrate s.atEnd
  result = newSeq[(float, int)]()
  while not s.atEnd:
    let element = (s.readFloat64.float, s.readInt64.int)
    result.add(element)
  s.close()


let data = @[(1.0, 1), (2.0, 2)]

store("tmp.dat", data)
let dataLoaded = load("tmp.dat")

echo dataLoaded
```